# Shimano shoe fitter

Tags: mountain-bike, shimano, shoes

I'd like to ask your support to decide which Shimano shoe size is best for me.

I am about to purchase Shimano SH-M162, but just noticed that the sizing is in european base. My usual running shoes are a size 9.5 (fit is roomy) which would equal 43.5 (based on Shimano's chart).

But the issue comes here:

My usual go-to-work shoe is a size 27cm (Mexico here), which would equal a 42.5; now, to add offense to injury, I've got a pair of european sized shoes, which put my feet at size 41.

Since this shoes will be bought via internet with no way of actually having them fit on a shop or anything (the model's not common in Mexico, and the only store that carries em want 230 USD vs 120 USD online) I'd like to ask any Shimano user that wears a similar size to let me know

**'What is the size of your feet?'**

Based on this, I can purchase the best sizing.

Thanks for all your comments in advance.

Best regards

---

In the end, size 43 was the good one.

Thanks for your F/B!

Comment: Answers online seem to be mixed. [MTB Forum](http://forums.mtbr.com/apparel-protection/shimano-shoe-sizes-compared-nike-735662.html) and [google search](https://www.google.com.au/webhp?q=shimano%20shoe%20sizing%20compared%20to%20other%20brands) I've always either bought shoes to match what I have, or tried them on. Specifically because of fears like yours. FWIW MTBForum suggests Shimano are on the loose side, at least for MTB shoes.

Comment: I'm on the fence about this question, it's very shopping oriented and quite specific, but the underlying "how do different manufacturer's shoe sizes compare" is a real one.

Comment: Mσᶎ, thanks for your comments. Main issue. is that, in Mexico, there is not a lot of stores in which to buy MTB shoes, that's why I purchase it from USA.

Comment: Note that generally a given manufacturer will use the same size standards throughout their line.  If you can find a buddy with Shimano shoes about your side (and not too terribly worn), see if he will let you try them on for size.  The size should be identified inside the tongue or somewhere.

Comment: (Uh, make that "... about your size ...")

Answer (score 3):

My answer is going to be a non-answer in the sense that shoe sizes are not really the same even among most types of shoes. As an example, when I buy shoes, I normally buy (in US sizes) 12.5 wide /13 in New Balance (which feels fine), 13 in Nike (which feels fine or slightly tight), 13 in Adidas (which typically feel tight), something bigger for boots typically, etc.

I find cycling shoes have similar variations but typically run smaller than the equivalent US size marking. You also have to consider not just the "size" but width, so if you have wider feet, cycling shoes become more problematic in sizing as well (I find that they typically run narrower than the sneakers I buy).

Remember, your feet aren't just a length - they have a width and height associated with them, along with curvatures, so it would be somewhat difficult to move others experiences to your size (especially since not everyone wears the right size of shoes to begin with)!

Comment: Upvote for this. Shoes are really something you should buy in person. Even different models across the same brand, or the next years version of the same model can have some variation. Even within the same year and model there can be some differences due to manufacturing irregularities. Make sure you wear similar socks to what you would during a ride. With winter boots I usually buy larger as my socks are thicker, and with sandals sometimes I have to buy smaller to account for the lack of socks. Some take this into account when sizing. Shoes and frames are the 2 things you should buy in a shop.

Comment: +1 - Great answer (informative & concise) for what is essentially an unanswerable question.